# Are there any way to detect if built in backward and forward button is clicked in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

Are there any way to check if forward or backward button is clicked in Flutter Web ? I was able to restrict user backward button for OTP but I need to prevent user from getting to the OTP page if they click return to log in page. the willonscope/poponscope only react if the page is popped IIRC, it did not tell you which button is pushed